# Error 52 Bad filename for VBA accessing network share

Tags: vba, file-permissions, network-share

I have a macro in an excel spreadsheet that uses Dir(path) to access a folder on a network share.
This works on my PC logged in with a local admin account, and with others using the same user account as the server holding the folder.
Using any other user account on the network gives Error 52.

I am assuming that this is a problem with access permissions on the file server.
I have added the additional users and allowed full control on the required folder.

Does anyone have any suggestions to what else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is right: there is a problem with access permissions. Also, if you try to access the `c` file inside the `b` folder inside the `a` folder, then it is not enough to grant access to the `c` file to the given user(s), you need to also make sure that the given user(s) have access to folder `a` and folder `b` as well. Basically, you need to make sure that the user(s) have access to the file and all folders in the path. Also, it is a very bad approach to give full access to people, you need to grant only the privileges you want to grant, so I would change the approach as well if I were you.